# How to access the grub boot menu in order to generate bootchart?

Tags: boot, grub2, configuration, bootchart

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, and I want to generate a bootchart to help me diagnose some system problems. However in [the guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) it says:

[image]

So how do I access the grub boot menu in order to append this text? And just to be clear, how should the line look once I have appended the necessary text? Also, is grub already installed for I don't appear to have either or these packages: `grub` or `grub2`?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this once you can press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot line and add the required entry manually.

If you want a permanent entry you need to edit the file

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

add the entry at the end of  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and issue

```
sudo update-grub
```

the line should look like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash init=/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart"
```

to update the changes.

Comment: Sorry, I have never gone into grub before, when and where do I press `e`?

Comment: When the system starts and you get the OS selection if you dual boot.

Comment: I don't dual-boot, can't I just edit the `/etc/default/grub` file to include that information? Do I need to `e` pressing bit?

Comment: If you don't dual boot you can press and hold first `Shift` at the start, (I think), to see the grub menu and then `e` to add the changes. Alternatively, you can edit then `grub`  file.